# How to map lists with ValueInjector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, valueinjecter

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3`.

Can someone please help me clarify what's happening here:

```
var person = new PersonRepository().Get();

var personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
personViewModel.InjectFrom<LoopValueInjection>(person)
     .InjectFrom<CountryToLookup>(person);
```

I have a grid on my `Index` view.  Each row is an instance of a `CategoryViewModel`.  So what I do is to get a list of all the categories and then map each `Category` to a CategoryViewModel, and then pass this list of CategoryViewModels to the view.  Hou would I do a mapping like that?

```
IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = categoryService.GetAll();
```

I thought the following would work but it doesn't:

```
// Mapping
IList<CategoryViewModel> viewModelList = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
viewModelList.InjectFrom(categoryList);
```

Comment: you can also look here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Automapper%20Simulation&referringTitle=Home if you want something more like automapper

Comment: @ChuckNorris: Did you miss the tag "valueinjector"? ;)

Comment: yes, I gave you a link to an valueinjecter page, there is shown how to use the valueinjecter in a more automated way. Umbraco CMS uses this approach

Answer (score 47, accepted):

AFAIK value injecter doesn't support automatic collection mapping like AutoMapper but you could use a simple LINQ expression and operate on each element:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = categoryService.GetAll();
IList<CategoryViewModel> viewModelList = categoryList
    .Select(x => new CategoryViewModel().InjectFrom(x)).Cast<CategoryViewModel>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Create an extension method instead and you'll get +1 (to avoid repeated code)

Comment: Thanks: I did that but then I get the following: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyProject.Web.Common.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. Puting `(IList<CategoryViewModel>)` for the casting be sufficient?

Comment: @jgauffin: I have no idea how to create an extension :) You feel like doing it?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: see my separate answer.

Comment: @BrendanVogt I've added a Cast<T> in Darin's answers, try now

Comment: @Chuck Norris:  Thanks.  I had initially put in the Cast, but forgot to put in ToList().

Answer (score 25):

```
//source list
IEnumerable<string> items = new string[] { "1", "2" };

// target list
List<int> converted = new List<int>();

// inject all
converted.InjectFrom(items);
```

And the extension method:

```
public static ICollection<TTo> InjectFrom<TFrom, TTo>(this ICollection<TTo> to, IEnumerable<TFrom> from) where TTo : new()
{
    foreach (var source in from)
    {
        var target = new TTo();
        target.InjectFrom(source);
        to.Add(target);
    }
    return to;
}
```

`ICollection<T>` is the interface that got least features but a `Add` method.

**Update**

An example using more proper models:

```
var persons = new PersonRepository().GetAll();
var personViewModels = new List<PersonViewModel>();
personViewModels.InjectFrom(persons);
```

**Update - Inject from different sources**

```
public static ICollection<TTo> InjectFrom<TFrom, TTo>(this ICollection<TTo> to, params IEnumerable<TFrom>[] sources) where TTo : new()
{
    foreach (var from in sources)
    {
        foreach (var source in from)
        {
            var target = new TTo();
            target.InjectFrom(source);
            to.Add(target);
        }
    }
    return to;
}
```

Usage:

```
var activeUsers = new PersonRepository().GetActive();
var lockedUsers = new PersonRepository().GetLocked();
var personViewModels = new List<PersonViewModel>();

personViewModels.InjectFrom(activeUsers, lockedUsers);
```

Comment: the default InjectFrom works only for object types, it's not going to do anything with int and string

Comment: @ChuckNorris: Strange. I testrun the code before posting it. Worked fine. Must be a bug in my copy of valueinjecter. Anyhow, the type is not important. The example works fine for collections

Comment: Can this extension method be expanded so that we can inject from multiple sources where each source is a List? Thanks.

Comment: @jgauffin thanks for the extension methods, making my life easier!

Comment: BRILLIANT! Worked for me

Comment: is there a way to enhance the answer with `yield`?

Comment: Ha!  Found this answer again almost 3 years to the day later.  I had forgotten that I found your extension methods in the past and implemented them.  Just recently I changed jobs and went to use InjectFromList (I renamed it slightly to help other team members find it) and it wasn't there.  It's a smooth solution that so seamlessly integrates with your daily work that you forget it's there!

Answer (score 2):

Use this function definition

```
public static object InjectCompleteFrom(this object target, object source)
{
    if (target.GetType().IsGenericType &&
        target.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() != null && 
        target.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces() != null &&
        target.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces()
              .Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)) && 
        source.GetType().IsGenericType &&
        source.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() != null &&
        source.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces() != null &&
        source.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces()
              .Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    {
        var t = target.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var tlist = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        var addMethod = tlist.GetMethod("Add");

        foreach (var sourceItem in source as IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = Activator.CreateInstance(t).InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(sourceItem);
            addMethod.Invoke(target, new[] { e });
        }

        return target;
    }
    else
    {
        return target.InjectFrom(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer work on `object` that are any type of collection like `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`?

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who prefer shortest notations possible

```
public static ICollection<TTarget> InjectFromList<TTarget, TOrig>(this ICollection<TTarget> target, ICollection<TOrig> source) where TTarget : new()
{
    source.Select(r => new TTarget().InjectFrom(r))
       .Cast<TTarget>().ToList().ForEach(e => target.Add(e));
    return target;
}
public static ICollection<TTarget> InjectFromList<TTarget, TOrig>(this ICollection<TTarget> target, params ICollection<TOrig>[] sources) where TTarget : new()
{
    sources.ToList().ForEach(s => s.ToList().Select(r => new TTarget().InjectFrom(r))
       .Cast<TTarget>().ToList().ForEach(e => target.Add(e)));
    return target;
}
```

Comment: how about now? @jgauffin

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic list mapper:

```
public class ValueMapper
{
     public static TResult Map<TResult>(object item) where TResult : class
    {
        return item == null ? null : Mapper.Map<TResult>(item);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MapList<TResult>(IEnumerable<object> items) where TResult : class
    {
        return items?.Select(i => Mapper.Map<TResult>(i));
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the ValueMapper class wherever you want, and call both `Map` and `MapList`

```
var mydtos = ValueMapper.MapList<MyDto>(dtos);
var mydto = ValueMapper.Map<MyDto>(dto);
```