# Does Value Injecter map collection properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, valueinjecter

I'm trying to map a collection of EntityFramework objects with a collection of view models.

```
 public class Channel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelListViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Using the code below the Reports list is not being mapped.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 IList<ChannelListViewModel> viewModelList = channelList.Select(x => new ChannelListViewModel().InjectFrom(x)).Cast<ChannelListViewModel>().ToList();
```

Comment: actually this should work, the value of Reports property should be copied on the other side, because they are of the same name `Reports` and type `IEnumerable<Report>`; probably you havent showed the actual viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by default, you have to use a custom injecter. This is why I switched back to automapper after trying out valueinjecter. [How to map lists with ValueInjector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872405/how-to-map-lists-with-valueinjector)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So it doesn't handle collections and the method you linked seems to work but what about properties that are collections?

Comment: a collection is also a property, and if there is going to be a property with the same name and type at other side then the value is going to be copied

Comment: oh God... I almost loved VI until found it doesn't support such mega-important feature. It's much easier to write `InjectFrom` extension for AutoMapper than write `CollectionsConvention` for `Injecter`.

Answer (score 1):

there's an automapper simulation which does that:

http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/60311#DownloadId=318259

you can download it and see how collections are mapped automatically

here's the article: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Automapper%20Simulation&referringTitle=Home

you can see the unit tests there

Comment: The AutoMapper simulation doesn't seem to work quite right.  It maps collection data incorrectly on objects that have more than one collection.