# Copy nancyfx response's cookie and header without foreach

Tags: c#, nancy, valueinjecter

In `IResponseProcessor.Process`

```
string format = context.Request.Query["format"].Value ?? "json";
format = format.ToLower();
Response response;
switch (format)
{
    case "protbuf":
        response = // balabalabala
    break;
    case "yaml":
        response = // balabalabala
    break;
    case "xml":
        response = // balabalabala
    break;
    case "jsonp":
        response = // balabalabala
    break;
    case "json":
    default:
        response = new JsonResponse(apiResponse, new DefaultJsonSerializer());
        break;
}
if (context.Response != null)
{
    // for test
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(new NancyCookie("wener", "cool"));
    //response.Cookies.InjectFrom(context.Response.Cookies);
    //response.Headers.InjectFrom(context.Response.Headers);
}
return response;
```

[ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) can not deal with List,because the NancyCookie dose not hava parameter-less ctor,I can not use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872405/how-to-map-lists-with-valueinjector) neither.

It is possible to copy cookie and header without foreach ? and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you on JabbR but we didn't catch each others questions and answers. :)

So to clarify, you want to preserve the cookies when you output a new response.

The problem is not adding the cookies to the response, you need to change the way you do responses.

Nancy handles content negotiation for you by default.

This means if you pass the header `accepts` with `json/application`, Nancy will see this and automatically send you JSON.

There is also a way to force JSON if you cannot change the headers, this is done by appending the type to the query.

Adding `.json` to the end of your URL will make nancy return JSON.

This is the same when using `text/xml` for the accepts and `.xml` for the URL, will return you XML.

---

If your request always returns JSON, you can do something like:

`return response.AsJson(apiResponse);`

This mean you're returning the existing response rather than creating a new one. All cookies will be attached, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I update my code.actually,the response type is depends on the query parameter, so I have to handle the response type convert.I try to find a way to preserve the Cookie and Header easier.Try to avoid the foreach here.Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @wener i think it might be worth reading this - http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/04/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-1/

Comment: Thanks,I forgot the `Negotiate`,`Negotiate.WithCookies` is what I need.